# MSTest V2 Collection assert with ignore case

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

Is there any way to do assert on collection using MSTestV2 with ignore case comparison?

For example with NUnit 3 assertions I can do this:

```cs
Assert.That(subset, Is.SubsetOf(superset).IgnoreCase, missingColumnsMessage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is a possible solution:

```cs
public static void IsSubset(this CollectionAssert assert, 
        ICollection<string> subset, ICollection<string> superset, 
        string message = null, IEqualityComparer<string> comparer = null)
    {
        var diff = subset.Except(superset, comparer ?? StringComparer.CurrentCulture).ToList();
        if (diff.Any())
        {
            var msg = message 
                      ?? $"These values are missing in the superset: {string.Join(", ", diff)}";
            throw new AssertFailedException(msg);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```cs
CollectionAssert.That.IsSubset(subset, superset, "Failed!", 
            StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```